# "cut" vs "cuts" in "His truck cut slowly across the field."

Tags: semantics

Consider the following two sentences. Intuitively they both sound grammatically correct. However, semantically it feels like there is something different but I can't quite figure out.

What is the formal explanation for the difference?

First:

> His truck cut slowly across the field.

Second:

> His truck cuts slowly across the field.

Comment: The first is past tense, the second is present tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb 'to cut' is an irregular verb. In your sentences, 'cuts' is the simple present tense, while 'cut' is the simple past tense.

You may find this link useful in the future:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_irregular_verbs

In my opinion, time spent by those learning English to understand it, and how to use it, would be time well spent.

Comment: There's a set of monosyllabic verbs ending in /t/ or /d/ that have zero plural suffixes. _Cut_ is a member; others include _bet
bid
burst
cast
cost
fit
hit
hurt
let
put
quit
rid
set
shed
shit
shut
slit
spit
split
spread
thrust_.